# I want to autocompile a java file using Java Programming (J2SE), is there any script tutorials?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [compiling a java program using another java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277170/compiling-a-java-program-using-another-java-program)

as the title below I want to autocompile a java file using Java Programming (J2SE), is there any script tutorials?

For example, i am creating an installation system for some java application. These application is creating another java file. But to use it, i need to compile it. How to make it autocompile?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you wanted. [jRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/)

Comment: Try `Runtime.exec` with javac command, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5619533/418556.

Comment: hi Thilo, thanks for your link. This is i need. Thanks.